# Receiving a string from user with only scanf and printing it. C language

Tags: c

Forgive weird formatting. It's my first post. In the assignment, I have to receive a string from the user using scanf("%c"), store it into an array (for example, string[5]), and print the entered string using scanf("%s). Everything I've tried has resulted in the string not being printed properly or only the first word. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char string[81];
  int i = 0;

  printf("Please enter a string. ");
  scanf("%c", string);

 while (string[i+1] != '\0')
 {
   printf("%s", i);
   i++;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: which string are you using to test it?

Comment: Using `%c` reads a single character, not a null-terminated string.  Are you looking for `%80[^\n]`?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia anything that has more than one word. Like "Hello world" or "Doing this".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no, I'm only allowed to use scanf("%C") or getchar()

Comment: Then you're going to need a loop around `scanf()` to read more than one character making up a string.  In theory, you could use `%80c` to get 80 characters, but that probably is not what you want (not least because it is not a null terminated string).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what would doing %80c do? I think that it has something to do with a max amount of characters before a buffer overflow, but could that make it take in the entire string?

Comment: It would read 80 characters, not stopping until it has read 80, or has encountered EOF.  See POSIX [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a char to hold each entered character, but it's a little tricky as you actually use a pointer to char. You also need to change your final printf statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char string[81];
    int i = 0;
    char placeholder = '0';
    char* a = &placeholder;           //pointer to char for scanf to load
    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    while (*a != '\n' && i + 1 < 81) {    //deref pointer for comparison (&& size limit)
        scanf("%c", a);
        string[i] = *a;               //copy char into cstring array (deref again)
        i++;
    }
    string[i] = '\0';                 //add the null terminator
    i = 0;                            
    while (string[i+1] != '\0') {
        printf("%c", string[i]);     //this prints char by char
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Edit[See comments]

Comment: My compiler (gcc-9.2 -Wall -pedantic) complained about that too! I tried setting ```char*a = NULL``` first and got a seg fault. I suppose declaring a new char and pointing to it is the way to go?

Comment: ...or  `char a = 0; .... while (a != '\n' && i + 1 < 81) ... scanf("%c", &a);
        string[i] = a;`.  Pointer variable not needed.

Comment: Oh, that's much cleaner. I'll just leave it as is for amusement /educational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Well  *print the entered string using scanf("%s)* couldn't get that but I think you're trying to do this without inputting all string at once.
This might be the thing that you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int somelimit = 81;
  char string[somelimit];
  int i = 0;
  int ch;
  printf("Please enter a string.\n");
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF ) {
    if (i < somelimit) {
       string[i++] = ch;
    }
  }
  string[i] = '\0';
  i = 0;

  while(string[i] != 0)
  {
    printf("%c",string[i]);
    ++i;
  }
  printf("\n");

 return 0;
}
```

Note that you need a buffer limit for this.

Comment: `if (i < somelimit)` off by 1.  Try `if (i + 1 < somelimit)`

Comment: what is off by 1 ? Here I defined `somelimit` as letter count. For your condition I'm going to store one more letter which I don't want. @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Consider when `i` is `80` then `if (i < somelimit) {` is true.  Then `string[i++] = ch;` and `i==81`.  After then loop ends, code attempts `string[81] = '\0';`, one past the end of the array.  `if (i + 1 < somelimit)` does not "store one more letter".  It stores up to one less.

Comment: I will check it when I'm available and make changes if necessary @chux-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%c", string);` only reads 1 character.  [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58867472/receiving-a-string-from-user-with-only-scanf-and-printing-it-c-language/58867760?noredirect=1#comment104004349_58867472)

Keep reading with `getchar()` until buffer full, end-of-line, end-of-file, input error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char string[81];

  printf("Please enter a string. ");

  int ch;
  size_t i = 0;
  while((i < sizeof string - 1) && (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    string[i++] = (char) ch;
  } 
  string[i] = '\0';  // Append null character to form a _string_

  printf("<%s>\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```